# Is there an equivalent way to Auto Fill to the last column in a row in vba as one does the the last row in a column?

Tags: vba, autofill

In order to fill down to the last cell in column X, I would do something along the lines of:

```
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AY2:AY" & Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Is there an equivalent way to fill all the way down to the last filled cell of an adjacent row to the last used column?

Comment: "an adjacent row to the last used column" ? Do you mean adjacent column?

Comment: actually now that I think about it, it doesn't necessarily need to even be adjacent. in the above code example it copies the contents of what the selection was all the way down from AY2 to the last cell with data in column X. What I want to do is the same but instead of filling down, I would like to fill to the right, and instead of counting rows in column x, I would like to count columns in row 2.\

Comment: So if you have data in A2:Z2, you want to fill data across from, e.g A10 to Z10?

Comment: No, data would be in the same column, so A2, and it needs filled to Z2.